# Reset Dropdown list on click

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have this simple dropdown menu that display provinces and cities. On load it display first the provinces, when I select one province it will display the cities.

What I want is after selecting the province and city and I click again on the select tag, it will reset again on the selection of the province.

***I'm using localStorage to save the selected province and city.***

hope you understand me.

thanks

[Codepen](https://codepen.io/gerryl1991/pen/bvVMrN)

```
function loadProvince(){
    $("#provinceCity").html("<option value=''>Select province</option>");
    for (var i=0; i<province.length; i++){
        $("#provinceCity").append("<option value='"+province[i]["id"]+"'>"+province[i]["name"]+"</option>");
    }
}


$(document).ready(function(){

    loadProvince();

    $("#provinceCity").change(function(){

        var selectedText = $("#provinceCity option:selected").text();
        if (localStorage.getItem("selectedProvince") === null) {
            localStorage.setItem("selectedProvince", selectedText);
        }else if (localStorage.getItem("selectedProvince") !== null) {
            localStorage.setItem("selectedCity", selectedText);
            var selectedProvinceCity = localStorage.getItem("selectedProvince") + "-" + localStorage.getItem("selectedCity");
            $('#provinceCity').append($('<option>', {
                value: selectedProvinceCity,
                text: selectedProvinceCity,
                selected: "selected"
            }));

            $(this).addClass("reset");
        }
        for (var i=0; i<province.length; i++){

            if ($(this).val() == province[i]["id"]){

                $("#provinceCity").empty();
                var cities = province[i]["city"];

                $("#provinceCity").html("<option value=''>Select city</option>");
                for (var j=0; j<cities.length; j++){
                    $("#provinceCity").append("<option value='"+cities[j]["id"]+"'>"+cities[j]["name"]+"</option>");
                }
            }
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: So what exactly do you want. First you selects the province, then it displays cities. After you select the city what should be done?

Comment: load again the provinces sir,

Comment: I already added a reset button in the previous answer. That will reloads the provinces

Comment: yes sir, I tried adding class on the element then call the loadprovinces, but didn't work.

Comment: I didn't get you. The reset button is one which  you are talking about, right?

Comment: sorry sir, yes sir, Im trying to make the select tag reset on click after I choose the city

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/166742/discussion-between-aneesh-rs-and-misdirection).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add province and city to localStorage during the time of option selection. And 
assign the values to new variable after the selection process is completed.  Then remove the province and city from localstorage for preparing selection box for the next updation
Js file

```
function showLocalStorageValues(){
  alert(localStorage.getItem("selectedProvinceCity"));
}

function loadProvince(){
   $("#provinceCity").html("<option value=''>Select province</option>");
  for (var i=0; i<province.length; i++){
    $("#provinceCity").append("<option value='"+province[i]["id"]+"'>"+province[i]["name"]+"</option>");
  }
}

$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#show").click(function(){
    showLocalStorageValues();
  });
  loadProvince();
  $("#provinceCity").change(function(){
    var selectedText = $("#provinceCity option:selected").text();
    if (localStorage.getItem("selectedProvince") === null) {
      localStorage.setItem("selectedProvince", selectedText);
    }else if (localStorage.getItem("selectedCity") === null){
      localStorage.setItem("selectedCity", selectedText);
      loadProvince();
      localStorage.setItem("selectedProvinceCity", localStorage.getItem("selectedProvince")+ "-" +selectedText);
      localStorage.removeItem('selectedProvince');
      localStorage.removeItem('selectedCity');
    }
    for (var i=0; i<province.length; i++){
      if ($(this).val() == province[i]["id"]){
        $("#clearBtn").show();
        var cities = province[i]["city"];
        $("#provinceCity").html("<option value=''>Select City</option>");
        for (var j=0; j<cities.length; j++){
          $("#provinceCity").append("<option value='"+cities[j]["id"]+"'>"+cities[j]["name"]+"</option>");
        }
      }
    }
  });
});

var province=[ 
  {
    "id": "820000",
    "name": "P1",
    "city": [ 
      {
        "id": "820001", "name": "C1P1"
      },
      {
        "id": "820002", "name": "C2P1"
      },
      {
        "id": "820003", "name": "C3P1"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "id": "830000",
    "name": "P2",
    "city": [ 
      {
        "id": "830001", "name": "C1P2"
      },
      {
        "id": "830002", "name": "C2P2"
      },
      {
        "id": "830003", "name": "C3P2"
      }
    ]
  }
];
```

Html file

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="provinceCity">
  <option value=''>Select province</option>
</select>
<button id="show">show saved values</button>
```

Comment: hi sir, can you help me again [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49271102/unable-to-load-json-to-custom-select-box)