# Unable to load JSON to custom select box

Tags: javascript, jquery, drop-down-menu

Im working on a [select box](https://codepen.io/gerryl1991/pen/bvVMrN) which displays province and cities and I decided to to use the code from [w3school](https://www.w3schools.com/howto/tryit.asp?filename=tryhow_custom_select) which converts your select tag to divs so that I can apply more css.

my problem is I cant load the data from JSON to that custom select box, and also the functionalities I made.

```
function loadProvince(){
    $("#provinceCity").html("<option value=''>Select province</option>");
    for (var i=0; i<province.length; i++){
        $("#provinceCity").append("<option value='"+province[i]["id"]+"'>"+province[i]["name"]+"</option>");
    }
}


$(document).ready(function(){

 loadProvince();

 $("#provinceCity").change(function(){

  var selectedText = $("#provinceCity option:selected").text();

  if (selectedText != 'Select province') {
    if (localStorage.getItem("selectedProvince") === null) {
   localStorage.setItem("selectedProvince", selectedText);
  }else if (localStorage.getItem("selectedProvince") !== null) {
   localStorage.setItem("selectedCity", selectedText);
   var selectedProvinceCity = localStorage.getItem("selectedProvince") + "-" + localStorage.getItem("selectedCity");
   $('#provinceCity').append($('<option>', {
    value: selectedProvinceCity,
    text: selectedProvinceCity,
    selected: "selected"
   }));
   setTimeout(function(){ 
    $('#provinceCity').click(function(){
     loadProvince();
     $(this).unbind('click');
     localStorage.removeItem('selectedProvince');
     localStorage.removeItem('selectedCity');

    })
    }, 500);
  }
  }



  for (var i=0; i<province.length; i++){

   if ($(this).val() == province[i]["id"]){

    $("#provinceCity").empty();
    var cities = province[i]["city"];

    $("#provinceCity").html("<option value=''>Select city</option>");
    for (var j=0; j<cities.length; j++){
     $("#provinceCity").append("<option value='"+cities[j]["id"]+"'>"+cities[j]["name"]+"</option>");
    }
   }
  }
 });

$( window ).load(function() {
  // Run code
     localStorage.removeItem('selectedProvince');
     localStorage.removeItem('selectedCity');
});
});
```

[SAMPLE CODE](https://codepen.io/gerryl1991/pen/MVKBER)

Answer (score 0):

Code wich replaces SELECT by DIVs runs only one time. 
When SELECT has changed later, it doesn't take effect.

You must run that code each time whan SELECT changed.

Just wrap code from [w3school](http://%20https://www.w3schools.com/howto/tryit.asp?filename=tryhow_custom_select) in function

Eg

```
 function convertSelect2Divs() { // Added. Start of function select 2 div
     var x, i, j, selElmnt, a, b, c;
     .... 
     .... 
     .... 
         for (i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
           if (arrNo.indexOf(i)) {
           x[i].classList.add("select-hide");
         }
       }
     }
  } // Added. End of select 2 div
```

And run convertSelect2Divs() at the end of functions loadProvince() and  $("#provinceCity").change()

Comment: sir can you update my code, I'm getting a hard time to make it work

Comment: I think you are talking about change() wich not firing. 
When finish with you div, you must to care about link between "selected" div  and "select"-tag.  Maybe rather use select2 Jquery plugin https://select2.org/getting-started/basic-usage  ? It supports refreshing and linking between created "div"s and "select".